# Compiling .jrxml design to get .jasper files with Makefile

Tags: java, makefile, jasper-reports

I have different jrxml files, I want to compile this to get .jasper designs.I wrote for this an ant build.xml file and it works fine.
Here's the used class :

```
 <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"> 
   <classpath refid="classpath"/>
 </taskdef>
```

Now i want to compile it with GNU Makefile but i can't find the class to execute for this.

How do I compile and get that jasper file with Makefile : Which is the class that have to be executed in jasper jar to get jasper design?

Comment: do you want to compile jrxml to jasper using java

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan yes :)

Comment: yes i'm working on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `JasperCompileManager` class to compile from your java code.

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
                our_jasper_template.jrxml",//the path to the jrxml file to compile
                our_compiled_template.jasper");//the path and name we want to save the compiled file
```